# What's the expectation $E[A^2(A+B)]$ given A and B are jointly normal variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose $A$ and $B$ be jointly normally distributed random variables with given parameters:

$\mathbb{E}(A) = \mathbb{E}(B) = 0$, Var($A$) $= \sigma^2_A > 0$, Var($B$) $= \sigma^2_B
> 0$, $\mathbb{E}(AB) = \gamma_{A,B}$

To find $\mathbb{E}[A^2(A+B)]$, can we assume:

$\mathbb{E}[A^2(A+B)] = \mathbb{E}[A^3 + A^2B]$

$\mathbb{E}[A^3] = 0$

$\mathbb{E}[A^2B] = \mathbb{E}[A^2] + \mathbb{E}[B] + \rho_{A^2,B}$    (is this correct?)

where $\rho = \frac{\text{Cov}(A^2, B)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(A^2)\text{Var}(B)}}$ is the correlation co-efficient of $A^2$ and $B$

Now $\text{Cov}(A^2, B) = \mathbb{E}[A^2B] -\mathbb{E}[A^2]E[B] = \mathbb{E}[A^2B]$

therefore $\mathbb{E}[A^2B] = \mathbb{E}[A^2] + \mathbb{E}[B] + \frac{\mathbb{E}[A^2B]}{\sqrt{3\text{Var}(A)^2\text{Var}(B)}}$, simplifying this to get final result

Is this a valid approach? Is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: Sorry edited, Var(A) and Var(B) are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A,B$ are jointly normal, you may write
$$A = \sigma_AZ_1 + \mathbb{E}[A] \\ B = aZ_1 + bZ_2 + \mathbb{E}[B]$$
where $Z_1,Z_2$ are independent standard normal random variables and $a,b$ are constants for which you may solve to yield the correct variance of $B$ and correlation between $A,B$.

Here, of course, both $A,B$ have mean $0$, so the expected value in question becomes $$\mathbb{E}[A^2B] = \mathbb{E}[\sigma_A^2Z_1^2(aZ_1+bZ_2)] = \sigma_A^2a\mathbb{E}[Z_1^3] + \sigma_A^2b\mathbb{E}[Z_1^2]\mathbb{E}[Z_2] = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, in regards to "a,b are constants for which you may solve to yield the correct variance of B and correlation between A,B."
Can you briefly explain or link to a source on how this is achieved please?

Comment: @CX You have $$\sigma_B^2 = \operatorname{Var}(B) = a^2 + b^2 \\ \gamma_{A,B} = \mathbb{E}[AB] = \sigma_Aa$$  Solve for $a$ using the second equation.  Then solve for $b$ (if you need to, use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that $b$ is real)

Comment: thank you for the explanation!